# ANDROID: on Notification received, I want to refresh the listView with the new data

Tags: android

Ths activity it's call from TabActivity.

And I want: if I receive new notification , I want to refresh the list of the current Activity.

```
public class TestListActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView lv = null;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.test_list, ListUtil.asStringList(TestServiceUtil.getTests())));

    lv = getListView();
    lv.setSelector(R.drawable.listindicator);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TestListActivity.this, TestViewActivity.class);

            // Next create the bundle and initialize it
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            // Add the parameters to bundle as
            bundle.putLong("testId", TestServiceUtil.getTests().get(position).getTestId());

            // Add this bundle to the intent
            intent.putExtras(bundle);

            // Start next activity
            TestListActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

I need just example, how i can make the refresh of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using notifyDataSetChanged() on the ArrayAdapter.